# ios could not locate NSManagedObjectModel , NSInternalConsistencyException

Tags: ios, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I know similar questions have been asked but they all have different answers and none seem to help me.

So, I've got an app called TherapistScheduler, which has therapistScheduler.xcdatamodel in a /Data folder at the root of the project. Inside that folder is a Session.h and Session.m file, which match up with my Session entity in my data model.

My app delegate has the functions *managedObjectContext*, *managedObjectModel*, and *persistantStoreCoodinator* in it.

Inside my applicationDidFinishLaunching method, I've added a view controller (loginViewController) over the top of my rootViewController (which is a tabBarController), and  I'm trying to access my Session entity from there.

I'm using the following code to try and save a value - this is throwing the error:

```
  // create session 
Session *session = (Session *) [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Session" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];  
[session setSessionHash:strUserhash];
```

The loginViewController.h file contains:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext; // in the interface declaration

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext; // after the interface
```

The loginViewController.m file contains

```
@synthesize managedObjectContext;
```

Do I need to do something in the loginViewController viewDidLoad to initialise the managedObjectContext? I'm a bit lost as to how this all works. I want to be able to access the data stored in the managedObjectContext from any view I switch to on the tab bar.

I know I'll probably need to add more code to the question, but I don't know what else is needed.

The error I'm getting is this:

```
TherapistScheduler[40752:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '+entityForName: could not locate an NSManagedObjectModel for entity name 'Session''
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x02581919 __exceptionPreprocess + 185
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0295b5de objc_exception_throw + 47
2   CoreData                            0x0004525b +[NSEntityDescription entityForName:inManagedObjectContext:] + 187
3   CoreData                            0x0007cd8b +[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:inManagedObjectContext:] + 59
4   TherapistScheduler                  0x000030ce -[LoginViewController processLoginForUserhash:andType:] + 142
5   TherapistScheduler                  0x000039fa -[LoginViewController connectionDidFinishLoading:] + 330
6   Foundation                          0x01f91666 -[NSURLConnection(NSURLConnectionReallyInternal) sendDidFinishLoading] + 108
7   Foundation                          0x01f915bf _NSURLConnectionDidFinishLoading + 133
8   CFNetwork                           0x02b8d9f1 _ZN19URLConnectionClient23_clientDidFinishLoadingEPNS_26ClientConnectionEventQueueE + 285
9   CFNetwork                           0x02c56c72 _ZN19URLConnectionClient26ClientConnectionEventQueue33processAllEventsAndConsumePayloadEP20XConnectionEventInfoI12XClientEvent18XClientEventParamsEl + 402
10  CFNetwork                           0x02c570ea _ZN19URLConnectionClient26ClientConnectionEventQueue33processAllEventsAndConsumePayloadEP20XConnectionEventInfoI12XClientEvent18XClientEventParamsEl + 1546
11  CFNetwork                           0x02c570ea _ZN19URLConnectionClient26ClientConnectionEventQueue33processAllEventsAndConsumePayloadEP20XConnectionEventInfoI12XClientEvent18XClientEventParamsEl + 1546
12  CFNetwork                           0x02b82dfe _ZN19URLConnectionClient13processEventsEv + 100
13  CFNetwork                           0x02b82c95 _ZN17MultiplexerSource7performEv + 247
14  CoreFoundation                      0x02562d7f __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 15
15  CoreFoundation                      0x024c11dd __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 333
16  CoreFoundation                      0x024c07c6 __CFRunLoopRun + 470
17  CoreFoundation                      0x024c0280 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208
18  CoreFoundation                      0x024c01a1 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97
19  GraphicsServices                    0x02de62c8 GSEventRunModal + 217
20  GraphicsServices                    0x02de638d GSEventRun + 115
21  UIKit                               0x00215b58 UIApplicationMain + 1160
22  TherapistScheduler                  0x00001f3d main + 125
23  TherapistScheduler                  0x00001eb5 start + 53
24  ???                                 0x00000001 0x0 + 1
)
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'
```

Comment: I can't answer my own question yet, but I had to refer to the managedObjectContext as a property of the app delegate not `self`. So it looked like `appDelegate.managedObjectContext`. I'll post my answer asap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to refer to the managedObjectContext as a property of the app delegate not `self`.  So it looked like `appDelegate.managedObjectContext`.

Answer (score 0):

When you passed the `managedObjectContext`, I think what you did is like this:

```
TimelineTableViewController * timelineTableViewController;
timelineTableViewController = [TimelineTableViewController alloc];
[timelineTableViewController initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
timelineTableViewController.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
//...
```

and then in `TimelineTableViewController`'s `viewDidLoad:` method, you wanted to fetch the data by `managedObjectContext`, huh?

I debugged this issue and found that `TimelineTableViewController`'s `viewDidLoad:` will be dispatched quicker than `timelineTableViewController.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;` (where you passed the managedObjectContext from parent (or the AppDelegate) to child). So when you were trying to fetch the data, the `managedObjectContext` is `nil` actually. That's why you got this issue:

> '+entityForName: could not locate an NSManagedObjectModel for entity name 'Session''

---

#### WORKAROUND:

What you have to do is to make sure that the `managedObjectContext` is not nil when you need to fetch the data:

```
TimelineTableViewController * timelineTableViewController;
timelineTableViewController = [TimelineTableViewController alloc];
timelineTableViewController.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
[timelineTableViewController initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
// ...
```

I just solved this issue by this way (no need to use AppDelegate's managedObjectContext directly).